# simply adding code to php function

Tags: php

I want to create a php function with the following code but when I add this to a function it stops working:

Code works:

```
    $arr = array(
        "index.php" => $home, 
        "about.php" => $about, 
        "details.php" => $details
    );
    $url = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

    foreach($arr as $key => $value){

        if($url == $key) {
            echo $value;
        }
    }
```

Code Doesnt work:

```
function metaData() {
    $arr = array(
        "index.php" => $home, 
        "about.php" => $about, 
        "details.php" => $details
    );
    $url = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

    foreach($arr as $key => $value){

        if($url == $key) {
            echo $value;
        }
    }
}

metaData(); // NULL
```

Comment: I think if you do not pass variables or make them `global`, they are not recognized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$home`, `$about`, and `$details` are all out of scope in your function. You need to pass them as parameters to that function for them to be available to the function itself.

```
function metaData($home, $about, $details) {
    $arr = array(
        "index.php" => $home, 
        "about.php" => $about, 
        "details.php" => $details
    );
    $url = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

    foreach($arr as $key => $value){

        if($url == $key) {
            echo $value;
        }
    }
}

metaData($home, $about, $details);
```

Comment: Yeah, so it was the case I wrote in comments. I wasn't sure, though.